# Javascript Autocomplete - ColdFusion - with unique identifier

Tags: javascript, forms, coldfusion

I have found this tidbit of code - which works fine.

But I also need an associated Identification ID pass along with the name.

So example has state say "California" - but I also have a unique ID associated to Califonrnia say "yye4" etc...

I can create my list easily with coldfusion as below.

```
             var getStates = function(){ 
                    return [<cfoutput query=ulist>"#username#",</cfoutput>]; 
              }
```

But I also need to pass a unique number in the form as well that is also associated to each username.

Thoughts?

```
     <html> 
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
      <head> 
        <cfajaximport tags="cfinput-autosuggest"> 
        <script> 
              var init = function() 
              { 
                    autosuggestobj = ColdFusion.Autosuggest.getAutosuggestObject('state'); 
                    autosuggestobj.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(foo); 
              } 
              var foo = function(event,args) 
              { 
                    var msg  = ""; 
                    msg = msg + "Event: " + event + "\n\n"; 
                    msg = msg + "Selected Item: " + args[2] + "\n\n"; 
                    msg = msg + "Index: " + args[1]._nItemIndex + "\n\n"; 
                    alert(msg); 
              } 
              var getStates = function(){ 
                    return ["California","Connecticut","Colorado","Illinois","Alabama","Iowa","Utah","Alaska"]; 
              } 
           </script> 
         </head> 
        <body> 
        <h3>Attaching an event handler to the autosuggest object</h3> 
        <cfform name="mycfform" method="post" > 
              State:<BR> 
              <cfinput 
                    type="text" 
                    name="state" 
                    autosuggest="javascript:getStates({cfautosuggestvalue})" 
                    autosuggestMinLength=1 
                    autosuggestBindDelay=1> 
              <cfset ajaxOnLoad("init")> 
        </cfform> 
       </body> 
       </html>
```

Comment: What is this tidbit of code to which you allude?

Comment: The Adobe CFAuto Suggest stuff - that works to get the autocomplete - but I need a second field populated with a unique id.

Comment: If the names are unique and the user can't change it, why is the name by itself not good enough.  Also, if the user can reject all autosuggest values and type whatever he wants, what do you do about an id field then?

Comment: I get what ur saying Dan - just when searching/inserting using all kinds of other code - I am using unique ids etc... Perhaps a better solution is an autocomplete select box...

Comment: For the states of the USA, a I'd use a select.

Answer (score 0):

This, roughly? I used a text box rather than a hidden field so you could see it in action.

```
<html> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<head> 
<cfajaximport tags="cfinput-autosuggest"> 
<script> 
  // itcodes would contain the unique numbers instead of sample names.
  var itCodes = ["Callie","Connie","Col","Illiana","Allie","Fred","Daphne","Alex"];
  var itNames = [];

  var init = function() 
      { 
            autosuggestobj = ColdFusion.Autosuggest.getAutosuggestObject('state'); 
            autosuggestobj.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(foo); 
      } 
      var foo = function(event,args) 
      { 
            var msg  = "";
            var nameIndex = itNames.indexOf(document.getElementById('state').value);
            msg = msg + "Event: " + event + "\n\n"; 
            msg = msg + "Selected Item: " + args[2] + "\n\n"; 
            msg = msg + "Index: " + args[1]._nItemIndex + "\n\n";
            document.getElementById('hCodes').value = itCodes[nameIndex];
        alert(msg); 
      } 
      var getStates = function(){ 
            itNames = ["California","Connecticut","Colorado","Illinois","Alabama","Iowa","Utah","Alaska"]; 
            return itNames;
      }

  </script> 
 </head> 
<body> 
<h3>Attaching an event handler to the autosuggest object</h3> 
<cfform name="mycfform" method="post" > 
      State:<BR> 
      <cfinput 
            type="text" 
            name="state" id="state"
            autosuggest="javascript:getStates({cfautosuggestvalue})" 
            autosuggestMinLength=1 
            autosuggestBindDelay=1>
        <input type="text" id="hCodes" name="hCodes" value="">
      <cfset ajaxOnLoad("init")> 
</cfform>
```

Comment: I apologize, I see where it is not working. I will try to fix.

Comment: Updated. Works in Chrome and Firefox as tested on CFLive.net. @Merle_the_Pearl

Comment: Cant seem to get it running. Might stick with drop down select boxes

Comment: Yeah, I saw Dan's comments on the question, and they are sensible. You might also check out the jQuery plugin 'Chosen' for future implementations like this. But, as Dan said, a simple select box for states is plenty enough.

Comment: Its not for states... Basically - 100's of users... States stuff just example coding...

Comment: If you're not averse to using jQuery, you might look at jQuery's "chosen" plugin. It may do exactly what you want.

Comment: If it's not just for states, you need a plan for values for which there is no existing database record.